# firebase how to query on firebase-util

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-util

I want to filter data from firebase, Im using firebase-util scroll for scrolling,

I have the following code

```
var baseRef = new Firebase(urlToFirebaseData).orderByChild("name").equalTo("john_doe");
var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(baseRef, '$priority');

// establish an event listener as you would for any Firebase ref
scrollRef.on('child_added', function(record) {
    console.log('added child', record);
});
```

this gives me an error

```
Error: First argument to Firebase.util.Scroll must be a valid Firebase ref. It cannot be a Query (e.g. you have called orderByChild()).require.18.r.Scroll
```

how can I query using firebase-util, I have tried putting the query in different places to no avail

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty explicit:

> First argument to Firebase.util.Scroll must be a valid Firebase ref. It cannot be a Query

The reason for this is that `Firebase.util.scroll` needs to build its own query to be able to implement scrolling on that location and Firebase only handles one query per location.

If you want to use `Firebase.util.Scroll` for the scrolling, you'll have to separate the data out into its own location so that you can do something like:

```
var baseRef = new Firebase(urlToFirebaseData).child("users_items").child("john_doe");
var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(baseRef, '$priority');
```

Comment: the problem with that is the data is structured in such a way as the first child has random keys and I have no control in setting it. Basically it looks like this {{-lskdsdfsf: {'name':"john_doe"}},{-tedsf: {'name':"jane_doe"},{etc...}}. I dont want to download the whole data to the client first, as 1 node has a lot of data

Comment: You'll need to restructure the data to make this work, David. Good data structure is key in scalable NoSQL data stores.

Comment: @Kato The data is almost flat, but I have no control how the data is stored in firebase, it is being set by another app which I have no control over, Is there another way of doing this?